# PHP CKeditor post via Ajax on blur strips html tags

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor, contenteditable, strip-tags

I am using the following php with ajax to post data on blur to SQL. It works fine passing basic text to the db, but I've added CKeditor to a few fields to allow WYSIWYG editing and I can't seem to figure out what's going on that's stripping out HTML tags and disallowing them to pass through.

Here is the php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
//database settings
include "config.php";
foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
{
    //clean post values
    $field_userid = trim($field_name);
    $val = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($val));

    //from the fieldname:user_id we need to get user_id
    $split_data = explode(':', $field_userid);
    $user_id = $split_data[1];
    $field_name = $split_data[0];
    if(!empty($user_id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))
    {
        //update the values
        mysql_query("UPDATE user_details SET $field_name = '$val' WHERE user_id = $user_id") or mysql_error();
        echo "Field updated to server";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Requests";
    }
}
} else {
echo "Invalid Requests";
}
?>
```

The js

```
$(function(){
    //acknowledgement message
    var message_status = $("#status");
    $("[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
        var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
        var value = $(this).text() ;
        $.post('ajax.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){
            if(data != '')
            {
                message_status.fadeIn("slow");
                message_status.text(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.fadeOut("slow", "swing")},500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's an example field of the HTML:

```
<p id="story1:<?php echo $row_rsTest['user_id']; ?>" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row_rsTest['story1']; ?></p>
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious. I am using the same CK editor in another instance with a form that posts on Submit, could it be a blur issue?

Comment: im confused as to why you use CKeditor, which creates html and then strip_tags

Comment: I'll tell you that's the first place I started. I removed strip_tags altogether and still for some reason the HTML tags are being pulled before they are hitting the the db. I'll update my PHP to reflect the removed strip_tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied also in the CKEditor forums: instead of using jQuery and specifically getText (surprise, that will give you just the text), use the CKEditor API and call .getData() on the editor instance.

Comment: HTF, yep, that was the culprit. Just to test I changed 'var value = $(this).text() ;'  to 'var value = $(this).html() ;' in the JS and it started working immediately. Now I need to modify the allowed tags in the CKE config to allow style attributes classes etc. I'd love to switch and just use the CKE Api to instantiate and use getData rather than adding the editor to all content editable divs. Looking at the code above, how would you convert over from the jquery?

Comment: Hi Andrew, that's a different question and you should create a new post for it with just the HTML and the JS code explaining exactly what's your new problem (of course, check the documentation and existing questions because that's surely covered)

Comment: Thanks AlfonsoML, will check the boards for an answer and post a new question (only if necessary :-)